# Changing Asp.net core Docker target from Windows to Linux

Tags: linux, docker, asp.net-core

I have created a new ASP.net application by Visual Studio 2019. When I was creating the project, I ticked the Docker Support checkbox and selected Windows for my docker. After a while, I decided to change my docker from Windows to Linux as I have some other software on Linux container and every time I need to switch. I did some research and I found out if I change the server URL inside the DockerFile, I can change it to Linux. By doing it I encounter this error: **Your Docker server host is configured for 'Linux', however the project targets 'Windows'**

Then I opened the Cs proj file and change the windows to Linux and now I see: Unable to copy file obj\debug\netcoreapp2.1\xxxx.dll to bin\debug\netcoreapp2.1\xxxx.dll. Access to the path bin\debug\netcoreapp2.1\xxxx.dll is denied.

I reverted the change but I still see the same error.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Edit your .csproj file in a text editor like notepad++
You should see DockerDefaultTargetOS tag, and it should read Windows
Change that to Linux

Answer (score 0):

- update your dockerfile, replace the base instruction by this line
  "FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/core/aspnet:3.1-buster-slim AS base"
- do the same with build instruction: FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/core/sdk:3.1-buster AS build
- update your csproj tag DockerDefaultTargetOS to point to linux